# phonegap app pause when capture image

Tags: android, cordova

I am implementing upload image to server feature in my application.
User can upload image in two ways, from camera and photo Album.

I refereed these links, and used that code.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer.

Main problem is, 
In first case when i open camera, the application is pause, and even not capture the image.

In second case when i open photo gallery the app is paused, but in this case i successfully upload video to server.
After finish this, app is resume, and loads index page.
I am using cordova3.6.4 version.

```
function captureImage() {
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});
}
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        alert("###1");
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        }
}
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        alert("###2");
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;
                alert("image path "+path);


       ft.upload(path,
            "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
            function(result) {
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("error ###3");
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });
}
```

Image takes from PhotoGallery

```
function photoAlbum() {
            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(
                uploadPhoto,
                function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                {
                    quality         : 50,
                    destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                }
            );
}

        function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = {};
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
        }
```

I get warnings in  logcat as

```
05-25 17:11:40.534: W/PluginManager(27869): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Capture.captureImage blocked the main thread for 51ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-25 17:11:40.564: D/CordovaActivity(27869): Paused the application!
05-25 17:11:40.564: D/CordovaWebView(27869): Handle the pause
05-25 17:11:40.564: D/Socket_Pool(27869): Failed to create TCP Fin Aggregation interface.
05-25 17:11:40.564: D/Socket_Pool(27869): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
05-25 17:11:40.564: D/Socket_Pool(27869): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
05-25 17:11:40.564: D/Socket_Pool(27869): Failed to create TCP Fin Aggregation interface.
05-25 17:11:40.564: D/Socket_Pool(27869): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
05-25 17:11:40.564: D/Socket_Pool(27869): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
```

Case 2 logcat warnings

```
05-25 17:51:23.964: W/PluginManager(28392): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Camera.takePicture blocked the main thread for 25ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-25 17:51:23.994: D/CordovaActivity(28392): Paused the application!
05-25 17:51:23.994: D/CordovaWebView(28392): Handle the pause
05-25 17:51:24.004: D/Socket_Pool(28392): Failed to create TCP Fin Aggregation interface.
05-25 17:51:24.004: D/Socket_Pool(28392): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
05-25 17:51:24.004: D/Socket_Pool(28392): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
05-25 17:51:24.004: D/Socket_Pool(28392): Failed to create TCP Fin Aggregation interface.
05-25 17:51:24.004: D/Socket_Pool(28392): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
05-25 17:51:24.004: D/Socket_Pool(28392): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
```

Comment: Sorry - whats the issue with the second case?

Comment: In second case, after image uploading app pause. I need, once finish image uploading come back to previous page.

Comment: Go to the previous page once the image has been correctly uploaded? In that case you have to give body to that function 'win' on the 'upload' function with, for example, window.history.back();